# Add initial data to the database

Tags: django, django-south

When applying a recent migration to my app, I encountered the following message in the output:

```
 - Loading initial data for myapp
```

I had a bit of a Eureka moment. It seems like it's possible to have South inject initial data into the database after performing a migration. How can I do this?

Comment: Here is a great blog article on how to dump existing model data into json fixtures and add them to a south migration:
http://djangotricks.blogspot.com/2012/09/initial-data-using-south-migrations.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you can tell South what data to inject [the same way you tell syncdb](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/commands.html#initial-data-and-post-syncdb) - using [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/).

Comment: Essentially, create a folder called `fixtures` in your app's directory, then in that directory create a file called `initial_data.(yaml|xml|json)` with the data you'd like to insert. Run `django-admin migrate` or `django-admin syncdb` to apply the initial data. \m/

Comment: to add, if you already have some data, you can dump it to a file by running manage.py dumpdata app app.Modelname >> somefile from you project directory.